# How to delay the sound of the piezo buzzer.in arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I'm trying to implement a car warning sound using a piezo buzzer and an ultrasonic sensor.If an object is 50 to 30 cm away, it will sound for 1 second and try to turn off the sound for 1 second, but I can't think of a way to implement this code. Can you help me? Here is my code.

```
#define echoPin 4
#define trigPin 3
#define buzPin 5

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(buzPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(echoPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

  unsigned long duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH); 
  float distance = ((float)(340 * duration) / 10000) / 2;  
  
  Serial.print(distance);
  Serial.println("cm");

  if (distance <= 50 && distance > 31)
  {
    tone(buzPin, 391, 1000);
  }

  else if (distance <= 30 && distance > 21)
  {
    tone(buzPin, 391, 500);
  }

  else if (distance <= 20 && distance > 11)
  {
    tone(buzPin, 391, 100);
  }

  else if (distance <= 10)
  {
    tone(buzPin, 391);
  }

  else {
    noTone(buzPin);
  }
}
```

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/77027/running-arduino-with-2-outputs-and-2-inputs/77028#77028

Answer (score 0):

After each time you tell the arduino to start making a tone (this is the tone() command) add some delay. To do this just follow the instructions bellow:

```
//code
if(statement)
{
    tone(buzPin, 391, 500);
    delay(x); //x=with the delay you want the buzzer to sound in ms
    noTone(buzPin); //after that the sound stops
    delay(y); //y=with the delay you want the buzzer to be silent in ms
}
```